# Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be successive positive zeroes of a nontrivial solution $y_n(x)$ of Bessel's equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be successive positive zeroes of a nontrivial
> solution $y_n(x)$ of Bessel's equation.
>
> (a) If $0\leq n<1/2$, show that $x_2-x_1$ is less than $\pi$ and approaches $\pi$ as $x_1\to\infty$.
>
> (b) If $n>1/2$, show that $x_2-x_1$ is greater than $\pi$ and approaches $\pi$ as $x_1\to\infty$.

**My attempt:**

I was able to solve the first part of the question as follows:

In case $0\leq n<1/2$, a nontrivial solution $y_n(x)$ of Bessel's equation vanishes at least once in any interval of length $\pi$. It follows that $x_2-x_1$ is less than $\pi$. Becase if $x_2-x_1$ is greater than $\pi$, then $y_n(x)$ vanishes at least once in the interval $(x_1,x_2)$, which contradicts the fact that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are successive zeroes of $y_n(x)$. Further, $h(x)=\left(1+\frac{1-4n^2}{4x^2}\right)$ approaches $1$ as $x\to\infty$. So in the limit, the Bessel's DE approaches the DE $u''+u=0$. It follows that $x_2-x_1$ is less than $\pi$.

However, I am clueless about the second part and haven't made any progress on it. Any hints or solution will be appreciated.